# Kill Long Running Processes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization, kill, mysql-slow-query-log

**Scenario** - you have hundreds of reports running on a slave machine. These reports are either scheduled by MySQL's event scheduler or are called via a Python/R or Shell script. Apart from that, there are fifty odd users who are connecting to MySQL slave running random queries. These people don't really know how to write good queries and that's fair. They are not supposed to. So, every now and then (read every day), you see some queries which are stuck because of read/write locks. How do you fix that.

What you do is that you don't kill whatever is being written. Instead, you kill all the read queries. Now, that is also tricky because, if you kill all the read queries, you will also let go off `OUTFILE` queries, which are actually write queries (they just don't write to MySQL, but write to disk).

**Why killing is necessary** (I'm only speaking for MySQL, do not take this out of context)

I have got two words for you - `Slave lag`. We don't want that to happen, because if that happens, all users, reports, consumers suffer.

I have written the following to kill processes in MySQL based on three questions

- how long has the query been running?
- who is running the query?
- do you want to kill `write/modify` queries too?

What I have intentionally not done yet is that I have not maintained a history of the processes that have been killed. One should do that so as to analyse and find out who is running all the bad queries. But there are other ways to find that out.

I have create a procedure for this. Haven't spend much time on this. So, please suggest if this is a good way to do it or not.

[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kovid-rathee/939c104784e966db55d45f7f71454387)

Answer (score 2):

Switch to MariaDB.  Versions 10.0 and 10.1 implement several limits and timeouts:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/query-limits-and-timeouts/

Then write an API between what the users write and actually hitting the database.  In this layer, add the appropriate limitations.